# Socket.io not Emitting from Client nor Server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

On client side, I have this code:

```
var serverAddress = "http://localhost:8081";
var socket = io(serverAddress);

socket.on('connect', function(){
    console.log("Connected to server on %s", serverAddress);
});
socket.emit("xxx", {text : "attack"});
```

And on server, I have this one:

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var socket = require('socket.io').listen(server);

socket.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('A user is connected to server');
});
socket.on('xxx', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

`connect` event is fired and caught on server, but `xxx` event isn't even fired nor caught. What's wrong? `Console.log` didn't report any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're confusing the socket.io *server* with a socket.io *connection*.

The server receives a `connection` event when a new client connection is made. The argument for that event (usually called `socket`) represents that connection. This is the object that you need to use to listen to messages:

```
// server
...
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
...
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('A user is connected to server');
  socket.on('xxx', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: This is what I've been looking for (y)